# How to get all elements of an iterator using slice() built-in function in python without using the iterator's length?

Tags: python, slice, built-in

If I have the following list: `my_list = [1, 2, 3]`. How can I take all the elements using `slice()` built-in method without knowing the length of `my_list`?

`my_list[slice(-1)]` gives me `[1, 2]` and `my_list[slice(':')]` gives me a TypeError.

Is there something similar to `my_list[:]` that I can use with slice so that I can define a variable before the list is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `None`

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(my_list)
1827682884416
>>> copy = my_list[slice(None)]
>>> id(copy)
1827682861888
>>> copy
[1, 2, 3]
>>> my_list is copy
False
```

I believe that `my_list[:]` is just a syntactic sugar. You can confirm this by `dis` module.

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("my_list[:]")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (my_list)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 BUILD_SLICE              2
              8 BINARY_SUBSCR
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see `[:]` syntax gets compile down to `None` and is [used to build the slice later](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/ceval.c#L4736).

Comment: It took me a lot of trial and error to realize that missing arguments in slice notation are equivalent to `None`.  I don't think it's documented anywhere.

Comment: @MarkRansom Doc does [say](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings) "substituting `None` for missing expressions".